# Search Data With Formula Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**A**             **B**

**Name**    **Colour**

Ahmad   Red

Patrick Purple

James   Green

Jacob   White

Hello, i have a table i  try learn using excel formula. I want to know how to find **color where name James**

if i'm using sql this squery like this => **select color from table where name='James'**

help me please

Comment: You should show columns.

Comment: You should definitely use Index Match combo.

Comment: Have a look at the use of index with match - you should be able to edit to your case easily, if it helps give it a vote : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55785168/4961700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is: `=VLOOKUP(B7,A2:B5,2,FALSE)`

This is how it looks:
[image]